# rewrite/mask external link inside article

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite/mask all external url in my article and also add `nofollow` and `target="_blank"`. So that original link to the external site is get encrypted/ masked/ rewritten.

**For example:**

```
original link: www.google.com
rewrite it to: www.mydomain.com?goto=google.com
```

There is a plugin for joomla which rewrite external link: [rewrite plugin](http://www.jonijnm.es/web/descargas/category/8-external-links.html?download=8%3aexternal-links).

But I am not using joomla. Please have a look at above plugin, It does exactly what I am looking for.

**What I want?**

```
$article = "hello this is example article I want to replace all external link http://google.com";
$host = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) == 'www.' ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0) : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if (thisIsNotMyWebsite){
    replace external url

}
```

Comment: I don't understand, if you replace the external URL's in your links, how do you expect them to work? Linking to a zip file does nothing to better explain the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: please visit the link I have given. here the demo http://www.jonijnm.es/web/wiki/66-demo/205-external-links.html

Comment: will all the links be `<a href="http://` etc ??

Comment: I am also looking for the solution. Tried searching online but no luck

Comment: solution depends on the format of the original text

Comment: @Dagon yes, links are inside anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse and traverse the document.

```
function rewriteExternal($html) {

        // The url for your redirection script
        $prefix = 'http://www.example.com?goto=';

        // a regular expression to determine if
        // this link is within your site, edit for your
        // domain or other needs
        $is_internal = '/(?:^\/|^\.\.\/)|example\.com/';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    // Parse the HTML into a DOM
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($links as $link) {
            $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
            if (!preg_match($is_internal, $href)) {
                $link->getAttributeNode('href')->value = $prefix . $href;
                $link->setAttributeNode(new DOMAttr('rel', 'nofollow'));
                $link->setAttributeNode(new DOMAttr('target', '_blank'));
            }
    }

    // returns the updated HTML or false if there was an error
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

This approach will be much more reliable than using a regular expression based solution since it actually parses the DOM for you instead of relying on a often-fragile regex.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
<?php
 $html ='1224 <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> 567';
$tracking_string = 'http://example.com/track.php?url=';
$html = preg_replace('#(<a[^>]+href=")(http|https)([^>" ]+)("?[^>]*>)#is','\\1'.$tracking_string.'\\2\\3\\4',$html);
echo $html;
```

in action here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7BYkoc

--my last update

```
<?php
$html =' 1224 <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> 567';

$tracking_string = 'http://example.com/track.php?url=';
$html = preg_replace('#(<a[^>]+)(href=")(http|https)([^>" ]+)("?[^>]*>)#is','\\1 nofollow  target="_blank" \\2'.$tracking_string.'\\3\\4\\5',$html);

echo $html;
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/JP8sUk

Comment: thanks dagon, but you forgot `nofollow` and target="_blank". I am a newbie so please dont mind

Comment: And also a if condition, If the link is from my own site then dont rewrite them

Comment: would you like a cup of coffee to?

Comment: Any RegEx based solution _will_ break at some point. `<a href = "http://www.example.com">Opps</a>`