# Replace/rewrite external links with php

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am trying to find a way to replace/rewrite all external links with php. We were using a js script which is useless nowadays since a lot of our users are using noscript.

For example

```
original link: www.example.com
rewrite to: www.mydomain.com?goto=example.com
```

Comment: This Answer will help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970744/rewrite-mask-external-link-inside-article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970744/rewrite-mask-external-link-inside-article)

Comment: I am not sure how I should use the DomDocument

Comment: Check given example